# Are there web frameworks built on the top of Vert.X?

Tags: asynchronous, vert.x

I know Play is a web framework built on the top of Akka. If I correctly understand, Vert.X is on the same level than Akka.

Is there something like Play but built on the top of Vert.X?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vertx 3 (due for first release end of this month I believe)

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web

For vertx 2, Yoke

http://pmlopes.github.io/yoke/